# Workflow not launch after scheduled apex changes criteria

Tags: trigger

I am fairly new to apex and I have a question.

I have a apex class that is scheduled to run at specific intervals.  When the conditions are met, it simply sets a boolean field as true.  This works fine.

I subsequently want a workflow to detect this change and take actions defined within it (send an email alert).  This part isn't working.

Comment: Workflows should run just like normal record updates. Looks like a problem with the workflow rule criteria. Could you post those?

Comment: Originally, the problem was as described, I had a trigger that updated a custom field with a value, when the value equalled X then the workflow should set a boolean value to true.  For some reason, the field change from the apex trigger didn't "register" as an edit.  however, if I manually edit the record and enter X into the field and save, the workflow fires.

Comment: Still we'd need more background info (such as trigger code, workflow criteria, etc) to give a decent answer,  because the way you describe it there is no reason to assume this wouldn't work.